# Empty Error when using Google Cloud Speech-to-text

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to use the Google Speech-to-text api from the App Engine (which does not require a credential key). However, when running the code to get the respond, I receive an empty error.

```
const detectspeech =  async (audioBytes) => {
    try {
        const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
        const audio = {
            content: audioBytes,
        };
        const config = {
            enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
            encoding: "LINEAR16",
            model: "default",
            languageCode: 'en-US',
        };
        const request = {
            audio: audio,
            config: config,
        };
        console.log("1");
        const [response] = await client.recognize(request);
        console.log("2");
        const transcription = response.results
            .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
            .join('\n');
        return { data: "Success"};

    }catch(e)
    {
        return {error: e};
    }

}
```

On the log, I got the number "1" printed out, but not "2", so I would presume the result lies in the line `await client.recognize(request);`. However, catching the error, I got the error with an empty field, like `{}`.

That certainly doesn't help much in debugging. So can anyone help. Thanks.

Comment: Add console.log (e) in your catch handler. What is displayed? Also this artice might help you with better methods to handle promises: https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
  res.send(await detectspeech())
```

Comment: Add more information to your answer that explains why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so a lot of this has to do with me being new to nodejs. Should have log `e.message` instead.

However, the core problem of the error remains, and that error is: invalid formatting.

So to anyone seeking to use Google Speech-to-text with Facebook Messenger (which is what I 
 am doing):

- Facebook Messenger will convert everything to .mp4 file. mp3 -> mp4, wav -> mp4 ... everything.
- Google Speech-to-Text will NOT accept mp3, mp4 sound format. They used to AFAIK, as in their [v1 RecognitionConfig](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig), there is a MP3 format support, but their v1p1beta1 no longer has it.
- If you text using their tool at their home [Speech-to-Text page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/), you will see even mp4 works, but that does not mean the API works with mp4. Why removing support for the most common audio file type? I wish I know. This may change in the future, but for know, it just adds more work.

So what you need to do, at least what I did successfully, is to use a file conversion API, like [Zamzar](https://developers.zamzar.com/).

Took me a while to set up using their doc, but then again, I am new to nodejs. Basically:

- Get the payload url from Facebook Messenger for the url of your voice clip.
- Pass that url to Zamzar for file conversion. Select format 'wav'
- Check the conversion status.
- When the status is finished, get the converted file.
- Encode the file to base64
- Pass that to Google Speech-to-Text API, which can easily recognize 'wav' files without too much configuration.
- Get the result.